# Stable Merge sort C

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I am writing a simple merge sort function to sort based on a given **compar** function:

```
void merge(int left, int mid, int right, int(*compar)(const void *, const void *))
{
  // sublist sizes
  int left_size = mid - left + 1;
  int right_size = right - mid;

  // counts
  int i, j, k;

  // create left and right arrays
  B *left_list = (B*) malloc(left_size*sizeof(B));
  B *right_list = (B*) malloc(right_size*sizeof(B));

  // copy sublists, could be done with memcpy()?
  for (i = 0; i < left_size; i++)
    left_list[i] = list[left + i];

  for (j = 0; j < right_size; j++)
    right_list[j] = list[mid + j + 1];

  // reset counts
  i = 0; j = 0;

  for (k = left; k <= right; k++)
  {
    if (j == right_size)
      list[k] = left_list[i++];
    else if (i == left_size)
      list[k] = right_list[j++];
    // here we call the given comparision function
    else if (compar(&left_list[i], &right_list[j]) < 0)
      list[k] = left_list[i++];
    else
      list[k] = right_list[j++];
  }
}

void sort(int left, int right, int(*compar)(const void *, const void *))
{
  if (left < right)
  {
    // find the pivot point
    int mid = (left + right) / 2;

    // recursive step
    sort(left, mid, compar);
    sort(mid + 1, right, compar);

    // merge resulting sublists
    merge(left, mid, right, compar);
  }
}
```

I am then calling this several times on the same **list** array using different comparison functions. I am finding that the sort is stable for the first call, but then after that I see elements are swapped even though they are equal.

Can anyone suggest the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: What is `list`? Why is there `malloc` but no `free`?

Comment: Not anything to do with your problem, but you might want to free the memory you allocate in the `merge` function.

Comment: Does `compar(&left_list[i], &right_list[j]) <= 0` (change the compare to <= rather than <) fix your problem so that it doesn't do the switch if they are already equal?

Comment: By the way, what is the type `B`?

Comment: I need to add free() yes, could this be the reason for the strange behaviour when re-calling the function more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will do it but try changing this line:

```
compar(&left_list[i], &right_list[j]) < 0
```

to this:

```
compar(&left_list[i], &right_list[j]) <= 0
```

This will make it so that if they are already equal it does the first action which will (hopefully) preserve the stability rather than moving things around.

This is just a guess though.

Comment: This change seems to do the opposite, making the swap even when they're equal.. If I run the algorithm once it does as expected, it's just then when I run it again on the updated list[] it does not seem to be stable.

Comment: Sorry about that then, just a blind guess. Try looking at an existing merge sort in C and comparing the code to what you've got? Or maybe step through the pseudocode on wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: I've just realised the function that is printing my output data is ordering in reverse order, so this was actually the correct solution after all! - palm -> face! thank you..

Comment: Haha it is Monday :P The '<' did look a bit fishy to me. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you got your sizes wrong

```
int left_size = mid - left;
```

And, as pointed by arasmussen, you need to give preference to the left list in order to mantain stability

```
compar(&left_list[i], &right_list[j]) <= 0
```

In adition to all of this, you are not calling free after malloc-ing the helper lists. This will not make the algorithm return incorrect results but will cause your program's memory use to grow irreversably everytime you call the sort function.